# Is there a generalization of the Lagrange polynomial to 3D?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, 3d, interpolation

What is a way to construct a smooth polynomial surface ($\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) with Lagrange-polynomial properties in every partial derivative? I want to try this for image interpolation.

Comment: Perhaps one of these (Wikipedia) references will do:
[Non-uniform rational B-spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline)
, [Bicubic interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) ?

Comment: @HandeBruijn I am talking about a unique polynomial of $x$ and $y$ that passes through all of the given points.

Comment: If you want to prescribe derivatives the topic is usually called hermite interpolation.

Comment: [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)
is susceptible to
[Runge's phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon).
That doesn't change in 2-D; actually it will become even worse.
So I wonder if you really want this.

Comment: @HandeBruijn, I knew about Runge's phenomenon. I anticipated that Runges's phenomenon would provide for increased acutance around images boundaries (high gradient). However, when I actually tested bilinear Lagrange interpolation, I found that the polynomial oscillated so strongly that I was left with mostly gray when I supersampled.

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance, but how can a (bi)linear function oscillate?

Comment: Do the given points form a rectangular grid, or can they be randomly distributed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you fix the value $x$ one variable you have the Lagrange interpolation formula

$$ f(x, y) = \sum_{k=1}^N f(x, y_k)\prod_{i \neq k} \frac{y_i - y}{y_i - y_j} $$

For each fixed value $y = y_k$ you can construct a Lagrange polynomial for the function $f(x, y_k)$.

$$ f(x, y_k) = \sum_{k=1}^N f(x_k, y_k)\prod_{i \neq k} \frac{x_i - x}{x_i - x_j} $$

The result is expansion in some kind of bilinear Lagrange basis.

$$ \prod_{i \neq k} \frac{y_i - y}{y_i - y_j}  \prod_{i \neq k} \frac{x_i - x}{x_i - x_j} = \delta(i = k)\delta(i = k)$$

We have constructed one of many possible [B-splines](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/B-Spline.html).

---

In theory the [Weistestrass approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) says continuous functions on the interval can be uniformly approximated by polynomials.  Using the argument above it makes sense that 2-variable polynomials are dense in continuous functions on the square.  This is a special case of the [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Stone.E2.80.93Weierstrass_theorem.2C_real_version):

$$ \overline{ \mathbb{R}[x,y]} = C^0\big([0,1]^2\big) $$

Using linear interpolation we can always draw some kind of surface connecting your control points and having the value specified, $(x_k, y_k, f(x_k,y_k))$.  The [Stone Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) says it can always be a polynomial and the difference between your approximation $f_1(x,y) = \sum a x^m y^n$ to your original function $f$ can be made arbitrarily small (as small as you want).

$$  \sup_{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2} |f_1(x,y) - f(x,y)| < \epsilon $$

It practice it would be really great to know the *degree* of the polynomials you find and how to build them (find the coefficients).   Splines let you do just that.

Comment: So is the Lagrange polynomial really a special case of the B-spline?

Comment: There are multiple problems with indices in your first section. One in particular is nontrivial: In the second equation, $k$ is overloaded as an index of summation and as part of the fixed coordinate $y_k$. If we try to simply change the index of summation to $j$, then the factors $f(x_k, y_k)$ should be corrected to $f(x_j, y_k)$ (recall that you fixed the second variable to be $y_k$), for which we have no _a priori_ value for all $j \neq k$.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce an auxiliary variable $t$ so that all three variables -- $x$, $y$ and $f$ -- are functions of $t$. You would have zeroes in four dimensional space like this:

```
t x y f
- - - -
1 3 7 4
2 4 7 3
3 4 4 9
```

The idea is to leverage Lagrange interpolation to have explicit formula for $f(t)$. However, with tabulation in this naive form, then it would be quite challenging to eliminate this newly introduced variable $t$. (It can be done with *Grobner basis*).

However, according to [1] almost every linear combination of $x$ and $y$ would also work. In our example let $t = 100 x+y$:

```
t    x y f
---  - - -
307  3 7 4
407  4 7 3
404  4 4 9
```

Now you have $f(100 x+y)$, which satisfies your partial derivative criteria.

[1] H.J. Stetter. Numerical_Polynomial_Algebra.

Answer (score 1):

While ignoring most of the OP's wishes, by far the simplest
interpolation between four neighbouring pixels is the bilinear one:
$$
P(x,y) = a + b\,x + c\,y + d\,xy
$$
Substitute the four neighbouring pixel positions:
$$
P(i,j) = a + b\,i + c\,j + d\,ij \\
P(i+1,j) = a + b\,(i+1) + c\,j + d\,(i+1)j \\
P(i,j+1) = a + b\,i + c\,(j+1) + d\,i(j+1) \\
P(i+1,j+1) = a + b\,(i+1) + c\,(j+1) + d\,(i+1)(j+1)
$$
Solve for the coefficients $(a,b,c,d)$ and substitute. Or make an educated guess.
Then for $i \le x \le i+1$ and $j \le y \le j+1$ we find:
$$
P(x,y) = (x-i)(y-j)P(i+1,j+1) + (x-i)(j+1-y)P(i+1,j) \\
+ (i+1-x)(y-j)P(i,j+1) + (i+1-x)(j+1-y)P(i,j)
$$
I would most probably stick to this if it were my research (but it isn't).